# Why am I getting a syntax error on the first line of this code?

Tags: python, syntax, mod-wsgi

I cannot understand what the syntax error is.

```
application(environ,start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    html = '<html>\n' \
           '<body>\n' \
           ' Hooray, mod_wsgi is working\n' \
           '</body>\n' \
           '</html>\n'
    response_header = [('Content-type','text/html')]
    start_response(status,response_header)
    return [html]
```

```
  File "test_wsgi_script.py", line 1    application(environ,start_response):
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
(scripts) root@django:/var/www/scripts#
```

Comment: ... What do you think the line of code should mean?

Comment: I didnt know, which is why I posted here.

Answer (score 1):

Do need def in front of the function call?

```
def application(environ,start_response):
```

Comment: That solved it. I don't understand why people post tutorials without testing thrm.

Comment: It appears that, not knowing the fundamentals of the language well enough to spot an error this simple, you copied and pasted code from a tutorial and expected it to work. I assume the tutorial writer's psychology was similar.